# PHP MySQLi insert get last column value add 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I'm trying to run an INSERT query into a table with 3 columns.  The first column is where I'm having the issue.

It is called COMM_CODE with VARCHAR value of 10 length, and is the primary key, ALLOW NULL is unchecked.

The values for COMM_CODE look like this:

```
 COMM_CODE
 c20188
 c20189
 c20190
 // and so on
```

What I would like to do, is when a new record is inserted, to basically add 1 to the most recent record.

Therefore, the most recent record is:

```
 c20190
```

So when I add a new record, the COMM_CODE for the new record will be:

```
 c20191
```

I tried this:

```
 INSERT INTO table_c 
   (COMM_CODE, COMM_DESC, DATE) 
 VALUES 
   (''+1, 'VIDEO GAMES', NOW());
```

But that just adds a number 1 to that column.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: How do you want to add 1 to a string?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to figure out.  I need to be able to get the most recent COMM_CODE, and then add to it.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution for your query :
To generate the new code I'hv created get_new_code function in mysql. I hope you know how funcions work in mysql.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_new_code`() RETURNS varchar(11)
BEGIN 
    Declare var_code VARCHAR(11);
    SELECT max(`COMM_CODE`) INTO var_code FROM table_c;
    RETURN (CONCAT('c',(convert(substr(var_code,2,length(var_code)), SIGNED INTEGER)+1)));
END
```

Just to verify your logic you can use :

```
select get_new_code();
```

So that you will get the clear picture.
Call this get_new_code function in insert query like this :

```
INSERT INTO 
`table_c`(`COMM_CODE`, `COMM_DESC`, `COMM_DATE`) 
VALUES 
(get_new_code(),'Description text',NOW());
```

This should solve your problem. :)